# Missing page files in project

Tags: database, project, rebuild

I have a situation where I have project which:

1. Contains 10 page files in project directory.
2. Contains 12 page in table Page in Access database.

I want to fix the project structure. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If there are missing pages in project directory, there should be CenterDb rebuild done.

Steps:

1. Open the project.
2. Run rebuild of center database.
3. There would be message that will inform the user what pages are missing in project.
4. The next is to remove missing pages from project structure in explorer.
   (or if user has access to missing pages, he should manually paste them in project directory)